Google Chat Bot Not Displaying Welcome Card on Direct Message Post-Installation
Description of the Problem:
I have developed a Google Chat bot using Google Apps Script and published it as a private listing in Google Workspace. When I install the bot from the Workspace Marketplace and accept the requested permissions, I am taken to a direct message chat with the bot. Here, I expect the bot to send a welcome card immediately upon installation, without requiring any additional configuration or authentication. However, after installation, the welcome card does not appear in the direct message. When I attempt to interact with the bot by sending a message, a "Configure" button appears, prompting an additional OAuth screen. I would like to skip this "Configure" step and have the welcome card appear automatically as soon as the bot is installed in the direct message.
Expected Behaviour:
Upon installation, I expect the bot to immediately display a welcome card in the direct message chat without requiring further user interaction or additional authentication prompts.
Actual Behaviour:
The welcome card does not appear after installation. When I send a message to the bot in the direct message chat, a "Configure" button appears. Clicking on this button triggers another OAuth authentication screen, which I would like to avoid. No error messages appear in the console, but the expected welcome card does not display.
The published bot’s behaviour is not consistent. The onAddToSpace function which is supposed to get triggered when the bot is installed is not getting called. Additionally the behaviour differ’s on how the bot is installed as well.

If the user install’s the app from the workspace app store. After installation we’re taken to the direct message with the bot where there’s is no prompt or no welcome message. When the user types in a message or a slash command then the user is prompted with the following screen.
￼Configure screen appearing
After configuring the user should be greeted with welcome message but the onAddToSpace function is not getting called.
If the user just searches the bot name in New Chat in google chat and clicks enter he’s directly greeted with the above Shay Bot requires configuration screen and once the config is complete he’s greeted with the Welcome Card.

